# Veryfing a String returns false?

Tags: java, android

Edit: I am new to Android, I don't want to use databases or etc to store the credentials, I just want to make the if statement to work...

So, I am trying to make a simple login system for an app. After I
press login, the toast returns the false message, but the strings are true, what I am doing wrong when I am trying to verify those? (if statement)

```
   package com.example.reevo.a02activities07;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import static android.R.attr.button;
import static android.R.attr.onClick;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewUsername, textViewPassword;
    Button loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        textViewUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        if (textViewUsername.getText().toString().equals("admin") && textViewPassword.getText().toString().equals("pass")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Succesfull!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: try with equalIgnoreCase

Comment: If you separate your boolean logic into separate clauses, then you can debug which one fails.

Comment: Logically, the only way for this to fail is if `textViewUsername.getText()` or `textViewPassword.getText()` doesn't return what you think.

Comment: I would call String.valueOf(textViewUsername.getText()) to ensure Nullpointer. Are you sure it's true? is getText not Requturning a wrapped object around the String. Isn't there a getValue or something. I do not remember exactly.

Comment: storing credentials locally isn't a good programming, and try to test your code with Debugger so that you can get actual issue. and use equalIgnorecase instead of equals if your credentials are not case Sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textViewPassword is pointing to R.id.userInput and textViewUsername to R.id.passwordInput. You should change it

Answer (score 0):

there is mistake in your binding controll check it
use this

```
textViewPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
textViewUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
```

insted of this

```
textViewPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
textViewUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
```